# Unresolved plugin:'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I get the issue when I download source of maven:

> Project: com.cinsoft:cinsoft-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>
> Location: /xxxxx/
>
> Problems: Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1'

My snapshot is below:

[image]

---

**Edit**

This below is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cinsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>cinsoft-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cinsoft-web Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- log start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log end -->
    <!-- pinyin4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.belerweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSONObject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- cxf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>cinsoft-web</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the pom.xml, please? And what is the error message you get, when you execute the `mvn clean install` command?

Answer (score 0):

I run to this issue before, try:

Clean the maven then downlod source again:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>